# How to execute scripts inside kubernetes pod from node js server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, node.js, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to execute scripts inside kubernetes pod from the node js server. I did find kubernetes client library for node quiet useful. The issue is , I need the script to be executed in multiple pods one by one.

Hence , I am using a 'for' loop which iterates over all the pod names and executes commands within them . But it throws websocket.js error for timeout.

The code is :

```
import { oraganizationMsps, organizations as orgs } from "src/constants/oraganizations";
import { throwException } from "../exceptions/exceptions.config";
import { chaincodes } from "src/constants/chaincodes";

const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node')

const { stderr } = require('process');

export class K8sQueryUtility {
    kc: any;
    exec: any;
    k8sApi: any;
    constructor() {
        this.kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
        this.kc.loadFromDefault();
        this.exec = new k8s.Exec(this.kc);
        this.k8sApi = this.kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);
    }
}
```

This is the exec command that executes the scripts .

```
async execCommand(namespace, podName, containerName, command, status) {
        try {
            await this.exec.exec(
                namespace,
                podName,
                containerName,
                command,
                process.stdout,
                process.stderr,
                process.stdin,
                true /* tty */,
                status
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
            throw new Error("Error in exec command: " + error);
        }
    }
```

And these are the functions.

```
async approveChaincodeNew(peer, channelName) {
        if (channelName == "" || channelName.length == 0) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("Channel Name empty"));
        }
    
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                
                    for (const chaincode of chaincodes) {
                        const command = ['bash', '-c', `./scripts/api/approveChaincode.sh ${channelName} ${chaincode.label} ${chaincode.packageId}`];
    
                        try {
                            await this.execCommand(
                                "default",
                                peer.pod,
                                peer.peer,
                                command,
                                (status) => {
                                    console.log(`Chaincode ${chaincode.label} approved ${peer.pod}`);
                                    // Do not resolve here, resolve after all chaincodes and pods have been processed
                                }
                            );
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                            // Reject the promise if any error occurs
                            reject(error);
                            return; // Stop processing other chaincodes for the current pod
                        }
                    }
                
                
                // Resolve the promise after all chaincodes and pods have been processed
                resolve("All chaincodes approved successfully");
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                // Reject the promise if any error occurs outside the inner loop
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }
    
    async approveAllChaincodesNew(pods,channelName) {
        
        for (const peer of pods) {
            const approve = await this.approveChaincodeNew(peer,channelName)
        }
    }
```

The error that is thrown is :
[image]

Is there any better approach to acheive the same. I'm using a gcp autopilot cluster to host the resources. Any help would be much appreciated